# I've made a responsive Grid with 2 columns but the heights won't end at same spot there is a slight gap

Tags: html, css

I have made a simple grid. I have two columns with a height of 650px and I have a margin of 2% and the elements in each column respectively add up to 100%.

The problem is the last element in the first column does not responsively match up with the last element in the second column. I have implemented a dirty fix for now but I need help to understand what I am doing wrong.

Below I have a link to my code pen. The sections in question are three and five. If you play with the width of the pen you'll see it either falls short or goes to far.

https://codepen.io/jasonwaynet/pen/djzBVW#code-area

This colFix is setting the height for both columns to 650px

```
<section>
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 colFix" >
            <div class=" relative services__serviceCard services__serviceCard--one">
                <p class='z-up'>one</p>
                <div class="overlay services__overlay"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="relative services__serviceCard services__serviceCard--two">
                <p class='z-up'>two</p>
                <div class="overlay services__overlay"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="relative services__serviceCard services__serviceCard--three">
                <p class="z-up">three</p>
                <div class="overlay services__overlay"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 colFix" >
            <div class="relative services__serviceCard services__serviceCard--four">
                <p class="z-up"> four</p>
                <div class="overlay services__overlay"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="relative services__serviceCard services__serviceCard--five">
                <p class="z-up">five</p>
                <div class="overlay services__overlay"></div>
            </div>

        </div>


        <div class="col-12">
            <div class=" relative services__serviceCard services__serviceCard--six">
                <p class="z-up">six</p>
                <div class="overlay services__overlay"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>
```